# Can not load png form react-web's bundle in React Native WebView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webview, react-native, webpack

Problem Solved！The reason why this is because the picture path is wrong! Is there a way to close the question instead of delete it? Hope this helps others.

I use webpack to pack react project to bundle.js, and use in react-native's WebView,which load a index.html like

```
    <WebView
        style={styles.web_side_style}
        ref={webview => { this.webview = webview; }}
        source={require('../src/index.html')}
        startInLoadingState={true}>
    </WebView>
```

It works well in web side,but CAN NOT show the image(png) in React-Native side.
Anyone know how to solve this problem? Do I describe the problem clearly?

...

Please forgive my poor English，this is the first time I have used English to ask questions

[react web can load png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMoVo.png)
load png in react-web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOEnr.png) 
load png in react-native (ios simulator)

Comment: We'll need to see your `index.html` and know the directory structure of your images

Comment: I have solved the problem.The reason why this is because the picture path is wrong.Thanks for your reply.It helps me closer to the answer.I'll update my question.